# Apps reverse positions on multiple monitors after resume from screen timeout

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, multiple-monitors, lock-screen

I'm getting a strange behavior on my Windows 10 64-bit setup recently.  I have a laptop with two touch screen monitors.  I generally have my Outlook open in the monitor on my left, Chrome open in the monitor in front (designated main monitor), and HipChat open on my laptop on the right.  Company policy goes to lock screen after five or ten minutes of inactivity.  When I log back in, at least twice now the Outlook and HipChat apps have switched screens.

What could be causing this?  Obviously this is not a major problem, mostly a minor nuisance, but it makes me wonder why.

Comment: *"Company policy goes to lock screen after five or ten minutes of inactivity."*  If you don't mind me asking, have you consulted your IT support staff regarding this situation?  If you are utilizing a company computer, there might be a lot of dynamics in the equation that can affect your Windows experience.

Comment: Point taken, but I was hoping someone else has experienced this and might have a clue.

Comment: Did the computer stay on, or did it sleep/hibernate before you logged back in?

Comment: It always stays on.  I shut the computer down overnight, but it never hibernates or sleeps while I'm at the office.